# PHP - PDO echo $array['name']; is not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, echo

I can't achieve to echo the associative values from my array.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    $servername = "my host name";
    $username = "my username";
    $password = "my password";
    $database = "my database";
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Street, Number, City, Country FROM extralocal");
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
?>
<?php
    $places = array();
    while ($place = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $places[] = $place;
    }
    foreach ($places as $place) {
        echo $places['Street'];
        echo $places['Number'];
        echo $places['City'];
        echo $places['Country'];

    } 
?>
```

For some reason when I `echo` each value from the `array` in the `foreach` loop nothing shows up on the loaded page, not even errors. However, if I `var_dump` the `array` I can see that the values are there, so I assume that the DB connection worked fine and the values are obtained correctly. It's just that I can't echo the specific values.

Any help will be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: replace $places['Street']; by $place['Street'];

Comment: @Poria, Nothing, same result. No errors.

Comment: You want to use `fetch` and not `fetchAll` in your while loop. Otherwise you will store all results in one subArray!

Comment: @Poria, actually your suggestion also was right, as using $places instead of $place was incorrect. Thanks again.

Comment: @Rizier123, I don't know how to vote for both answers as they both where correct, or I just leave it like this?

Comment: @Poria, I don't know how to vote for both answers as they both where correct, or I just leave it like this?

Comment: @Logixor Just upvote the answer which you found useful and downvote which weren't useful. You can then accept, if you want, the answer which helped you the most and solved your problem

Comment: @Rizier123 I updated the answer with your suggestion as well, thanks for your help in answering the question correct way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($places as $place) {
    echo $places['Street'];
    echo $places['Number'];
    echo $places['City'];
    echo $places['Country'];
}
```

replace by

```
foreach ($places as $place) {
    echo $place['Street'];
    echo $place['Number'];
    echo $place['City'];
    echo $place['Country'];

}
```

Use `fetch` instead of `fetchAll` in your while loop
Hope it solves your problem

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but unfortunately it didn't work :(

Comment: Ok, after I fixed the problem as @Rizier123 suggested in the comments I also found out that this was another problem in my code. Thank you!